# C# Try Parse returning 0

Tags: c#

I'm trying to parse a string to return an int like this :

```
private UserCredentials GetAddressBook(string userName)
{
  int addressBookId = 0;
  int.TryParse(userName, out addressBookId);
  return this.GetAddressBook(addressBookId);
}
```

My problem is that addressBookId is always 0. My userName is cara4.

Comment: `cara4` is not a valid integer

Comment: If `int.TryParse()` fails it returns false and initialises the `out` parameter to zero. And `cara4` isn't an integer.

Comment: `TryParse` can't return zero. It returns true or false. It returned false (which you don't know, because you ignore the return value) because you gave it a non-parseable string. `addressBookId` was left with its original value of zero because `TryParse` had no new value to give it. What led you to believe that "cara4" could be parsed as an integer?

Comment: Suppose your userName was `ca3ra4`. Which number should `TryParse` pick out in this case? It can´t guess, so if it can´t parse an input-string it returns false and leaves the out-argument stay zero.

Comment: What kind of relation does userName have to addressBookId? You cant just parse one value to the other and expect it to work.

Comment: *Are* we correct in guessing that the `addressBookId` of user `cara4` is `4`? That is that the addressBookId is always appended to the username?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cara4` is not a valid integer so you get the default value which is 0. Always evaluate the returned `bool` frrom `int.TryParse` to determine whether the format was valid or not.

Maybe you want:

```
private UserCredentials GetAddressBook(string userName)
{
  int addressBookId = 0;
  bool valid = int.TryParse(userName, out addressBookId);
  if(!valid) 
  {
      var lastDigits = userName.SkipWhile(char.IsLetter).TakeWhile(char.IsDigit);
      valid = int.TryParse(string.Concat(lastDigits), out addressBookId);
  }
  if(valid)
      return this.GetAddressBook(addressBookId);  
  else
      return null;
}
```

Side-note: this LINQ approach doesn't really return the last digits of the string but the digits that follow the first non-digits, so `"cara1foo2"` would return `1`. If your logic is that the `addressBookId` is at the end you could use:

```
var lastDigits = userName.Reverse().TakeWhile(char.IsDigit).Reverse();
```

Answer (score 3):

usually `Try.Parse` is used in an if-block. so that you only return if the parsing has worked:

```
if(int.TryParse(userName, out addressBookId))
{
    return this.GetAddressBook(addressBookId);
}
else 
{
    return null;
}
```

your problem is that the value of `userName = "cara4"` has invalid characters which do not represent numbers. The [TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) method will write the converted number into the `out` parameter if the conversion was successfull (in your case `addressBookId`). Otherwise it went wrong and you should not use the value of `addressBookId`